# Calculated Column: Nested If

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, formula

I am new to SharePoint and I'm trying to enable a calculated column in a SharePoint list with the following formula but it's not working quite well. It is not throwing me any Optimize nor Test attribute. I have tried everything but I still can't find the error.

```
=IF(AND([Column1]<3,[Column2]<3),"Optimize",IF(AND([Column1]>=3,[Column2]<3),"Test",IF(AND([Column1]<3,[Column2]>=3),"Monitor",IF(AND([Column1]>=3,[Column2]>=3),"Improve"))))
```

I would really appreciate some guidance or if you could point me to the error I am making. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it throwing any error? Are you using correct display names of your columns?

Comment: Try this: `=IF(AND([Column1]<3,[Column2]<3),"Optimize",IF(AND([Column1]>=3,[Column2]<3),"Test",IF(AND([Column1]<3,[Column2]>=3),"Monitor",IF(AND([Column1]>=3,[Column2]>=3),"Improve",""))))`. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Check my solution given below. Let me know if it works or if you need any further help on this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
=IF(AND([Column1]<3,[Column2]<3),"Optimize",IF(AND([Column1]>=3,[Column2]<3),"Test",IF(AND([Column1]<3,[Column2]>=3),"Monitor",IF(AND([Column1]>=3,[Column2]>=3),"Improve",""))))
```

**OR**:

```
=IF([Column1]<3, IF([Column2]<3, "Optimize", "Monitor"), IF([Column2]<3, "Test", "Improve"))
```

---

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display name* of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
3. Wrap column names inside `[]` if your column name has space in it. For example: `[My Column Name]`.

**Official Documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14))